# PHP para Service por CURL

Tags: php, libcurl

Estou tentando mandar dados do PHP através do CURL para o service do Protheus, que recebe uma *string*.

Estou com problemas no momento de referenciar os dados para a variável.

Exemplo em PHP:

```
$response2 = '[{"A1_COD":"'.$row['CLI_PROTHEUS'].'",';
$response2 .= '"A1_PESSOA":"'.$row['CLI_PESSOA'].'",';
$response2 .= '"A1_CGC":"'.$row['CLI_CGC'].'",';
$response2 .= '"A1_NOME":"'. $row['CLI_NOME'].'",';

$url  = 'http://blabla/REST01/ADRESTCR1/putcli';
$ch   = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '**dadosCli**='.$response2);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

O problema é para passar o parâmetro, a URL deveria ser `http://blabla/REST01/ADRESTCR1/putcli?dadosCli=VALORES`

Esse está sendo o problema.... se eu envio tudo direto na URL, dá aquele problema de conversão por conta de acentos e espaços.

Alguém tem alguma luz??? o problema é passar o parâmetro que precisa receber o valor.

Comment: Você precisa fazer uma requisição POST e os campos serão enviados pela URL?

Comment: Exatamente Anderson, passar o valor para o parametro "dadosCli" da URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função [`urlencode(string):string`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) retorna uma string em que todos os caracteres não-alfanuméricos com exceção de `-`, `_` e `,` são substituídos com um sinal de porcento (%) seguido por dois dígitos hexadecimais e espaços codificados como um sinal de (+).

```
<?php
$response2 = '[{"A1_COD":"'.$row['CLI_PROTHEUS'].'",';
$response2 .= '"A1_PESSOA":"'.$row['CLI_PESSOA'].'",';
$response2 .= '"A1_CGC":"'.$row['CLI_CGC'].'",';
$response2 .= '"A1_NOME":"'. $row['CLI_NOME'].'",';

$url  = 'http://blabla/REST01/ADRESTCR1/putcli';
$ch   = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

//Use urlencode() sobre $response2
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'dadosCli='.urlencode($response2) ); // Tirei os asteriscos pois julguei ser uma tentativa de destaque 

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Se for receber o valor em uma requisição de http não precisa se preocupar em decodificar o parâmetro com [`urldecode(string):string`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.urldecode.php) na documentação está destacado: que

> As super-globais [`$_GET`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.get.php) e [`$_REQUEST`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.request.php) já são decodificadas.
>   Usar [`urldecode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.urldecode.php) em um elemento $_GET ou $_REQUEST podem gerar
>   resultados inesperados e perigosos.

Apesar de não estar explicitamente documentado o mesmo se estende para [`$POST`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.post.php)

Comment: é isso mesmo,muito obrigada